# li.append(i) vs tu = tu + (i,)

Tags: python

My question is why storing data in a list and appending each new data point is so much faster than using a tuple and redefining the tuple at every iteration. My code:

```
def li(N):
    li = []
    for i in range(N):
        li.append(i)
    return 

def tu(N):
    tu = ()
    for i in range(N):
        tu = tu + (i,)
    return
```

If I run my functions with N = 100000 li takes 0.02364325523376465 and tu 24.86034870147705.

Is there a reason for this huge discrepancy in speed?

Comment: Lists are mutable. You can add more items to an existing list. With tuples you have to create a whole new tuple every time.

Comment: Because `.append` is amoratized constant time, `tu = tu + (i,)` on the other hand, is O(N) time. Thus, your first algorith is O(N) time, while your second algorithm is O(N^2)

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought creating a new tuple would be done in constant time too, @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Yeah, no, I wasn't really interested in creating a tuple, mainly wanted to compare the runtime of saving data incrementally in tuple vs list form, and the append i in range was the first thing I could think of. @Tomerikoo

Comment: @LegendWK anyway I was wrong. The expression I wrote creates a ***generator***, not a tuple... My bad

Comment: And as others said, albeit tuple being a light-weight structure, it's purpose is immutability. Which means it can't be changed. So if you're trying to use it opposite to its purpose, surely it's gonna cost...

Answer (score 3):

Lists are mutable. You can add more items to an existing list. Tuples are immutable. With tuples you have to create a whole new tuple every time. That is slower, especially when the tuple is big.

There is no reason to use the tuple version. If you want to gradually create a big tuple you'd be better off using a list and converting to a tuple at the end.

Comment: Yes, but lists are much "heavier" objects than tuples, but clearly it's inefficient to redefine them at every stage

Comment: @LegendWK If you *were* redefining the list at every stage, that would indeed be inefficient.

Comment: no, what I meant was the even though tuples a bit lighter than lists, having to redefine the tuple (like I did in the example) is inefficient in comparison to appending to a list, @khelwood

Comment: @LegendWK Yes, agreed.

Comment: @LegendWK "lists are much "heavier" objects than tuples" no, not really.

Answer (score 2):

In the tu function, there is the overhead of creating a new tuple object at each iteration. The

```
  tu = tu + (i,)
```

statement is syntactic sugar. It's ok if you need to merge two little tuples, but it's better to take the first approach if you need efficiency.

Comment: Yeah, clearly, I was just surprised by how slow the tuple variant was, given that it's such a light data structure

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the other answers and comments Lists are mutable and appending to list is `O(n)` operation, which simply inserts new element at the end of the list. You are not creating a new list at every iteration of the loop.

However with the tuple's version of your code you are creating not just one but two tuples in each iteration.

```
tu = tu + (i, )   # (i,) is also creating a new tuple and then you are recreating tu
```

In this particular case the operation is of `O(n^2)` complexity, `O(n)` for loop iteration and another `O(n)` for creating tuple of n elements, plus the cost of other operations, so clearly it much costlier function than what it just looks.

In simpler terms this is not even the use case of `tuples` which are a mutable data structure.

On a side note note for the list version you can even reduce the cost of the `append` method as well by using a list comprehension which do not make use of explicit `append`.

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Yeah, clearly its not the use case. But ok, the answer is that creating a new tuple is done in linear time.

Comment: @LegendWK its not Linear, it is O(n^2) time, updated my answer for the same.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said, the tuple creation part is linear, and so is the loop, resulting in quadratic time. I somehow thought creating the tuple would be constant, resulting in linear time. @Rohit